# Change bootstrap modal to static div depending on screen size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I'm working on a one-page app-like site that has a list of items that the user can click, to get more information about the item. On the mobile version I would like this information to pop up as a modal, but on the desktop (larger screen) version I would like the information to fill the center/right part of the content area.

I've considered a few things, but they all seem a bit kludgy: Using @media with screen to strip away (zero out) or add the modal and div styling, using javascript to remove/add the modal classes depending on screen size. While they work, I'm wondering if there's a way to do this cleanly with CSS, so that other bits of javascript run normally without having to do things like check screen size before updating a div (or triggering a modal).

Comment: Just for future reference. I had to do the same but jquery was required, https://jsfiddle.net/qnmzy67L/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code.
Here is the jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/nz3hte42/8/)

```css
.modal,
.modal-backdrop {
  position: static;
}

.modal-backdrop.show {
  opacity: 0;
}

.modal-dialog {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .modal,
  .modal-backdrop {
    position: fixed;
  }
  .modal-backdrop.show {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  .modal-dialog {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <div class="modal-container">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            ...
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
  </p>

</div>
```